# Can't reach Facebook site, ping works

Tags: proxy, facebook, web-filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user?](https://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user)

My country has filtered Facebook. When I use `ping www.facebook.com`, all packets are received correctly, but when I browse to http://www.facebook.com/, I can't see the Facebook site and I'm forwarded to another page. How can I fix this problem?

**After Edit:**

The other sites also ...

x.blogspot.com

x.wordpress.com
...

Comment: when you ping DNS hostnames, ping network packets are transmitted as ICMP. but when you visit it as a web site, it is using HTTP, which utilises port 80 or port 443 if on SSL. ICMP may not be blocked, but port 80/443 are.

Comment: Can I Solve it?

Comment: Your forwarded to another site? try pinging facebook.com, see what IP the name resolves to, enter that IP. It may bring you to the site you were redirected to, this will indicate the use of DNS filtering, I can see this as the easy way to block site ALOT of sites. It resolves to http://69.63.181.12/ in states try connecting to that IP it will at least give us more info about how they are blocking access to facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Check tor at http://www.torproject.org/ .

Comment: And Also It.I Live In Iran.

Comment: TOR is an viable solution, But you must take caution when using TOR.  Most TOR endpoints are nefarious.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to (or are willing to pay for) a server in a country where Facebook is not restricted, you could set up an [SSH Proxy](http://lifehacker.com/#!237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy) and browse to any site you want.  It would use the bandwidth of that server, so make sure the limits aren't too restrictive.  Any cheap web hosting plan would work (I've used Dreamhost for it in the past) as long as it has an SSH shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thus I don't really know how the site filtering of some countries work, my only suggestion is to try something like [BackFox](http://www.backfox.com/), to work around the filter, maybe this works.

Comment: And Also It ... :-(

Comment: BackFox is blocked, too? As far as I know, there are more sites like backfox.

Comment: @hosseinsinohe Are that any sites that work AT ALL?

Comment: Yes.It's Block :-(

Comment: @BloodPhilia Probably not that many. Check some news site for news about Iran.

Comment: @Daniel I know, but still... could've been an issue with his connection that would render all websites unreachable... Just checking! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the url but going through the web browser is giving you issues, you can try to take the DNS part of the problem away.

When you ping the URL, you will be given the IP address of the url: mine currently says

`Pinging www.facebook.com [66.220.149.11] with 32 bytes of data:`

try entering this ip address into your web browser. This will bypass the possible DNS issue as you are going through to the url directly.

Comment: It's Good.But Does Not Work

Comment: pinging "facebook.com" will probably give him the IP of the site he keeps getting redirected to since it is still using his dns servers to to resolve the name. We need to give him the IP from a working dns server.

Comment: @Kyle: which i just did above...

Comment: ^ha..... duh, it was early when I wrote that +1 for a good idea.