# Networking failure with bbc.co.uk - "error resolving hostname: timed out"

Tags: networking

Online connection failure with bbc.co.uk.  I am in Spain.  I have Windows 7 on my laptop and have no problems connecting to other websites.  But every time I try to connect to the BBC I get "Connection Error" with the details "Error resolving hostname www.bbc.co.uk:  timed out"  Have tried many different things but no success.  Am not computer literate.

Comment: Have you looked at our Community FAQ **[How to diagnose not being able to reach a specific website](http://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user)**?

Answer (score 3):

It is possibly a problem with your Internet Service Provider (ISP). Their Domain Name Service (DNS) servers may not be providing the correct results or their routers may have a fault in their routing tables or a connection problem to some parts of the Internet.

Here is what I would do:

### Check the name

Open a command prompt window (start, all programs, accessories, command prompt)

type `nslookup www.bbc.co.uk` and press enter.

You should get an answer like this

```
Server:  ns0.ispname.es
Address:  1.2.3.4

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.bbc.net.uk
Address:  212.58.246.93
Aliases:  www.bbc.co.uk
```

The first part is the name and address of one of your ISP's DNS servers.
The second part should be the same as above - although the BBC probably have many web-servers so the actual IP-address may change from time to time.

### Check the address

type `ping www.bbc.co.uk` and press enter.

The response should look like this:

```
Pinging www.bbc.net.uk [212.58.246.91] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 212.58.246.91: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=54
Reply from 212.58.246.91: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=54
Reply from 212.58.246.91: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=54
Reply from 212.58.246.91: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 212.58.246.91:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 49ms, Maximum = 51ms, Average = 50ms
```

### Check your ISP's routers

Type `tracert www.bbc.co.uk` and press enter

```
    Tracing route to www.bbc.net.uk [212.58.244.66]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

      1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.local [192.168.0.254]
      2    45 ms    43 ms    44 ms  router.zaragoza.ispname.es [88.2.3.4]
      3    44 ms    44 ms    43 ms  router.madrid.ispname.es [2.3.4.5]
      4    46 ms    51 ms    44 ms  router.other.ispname.es [7.3.5.22]
      5    44 ms    45 ms    46 ms  router.whatever.ispname.es [11.2.5.6]
      6    50 ms    50 ms    49 ms  router.somthing.ispname.es [34.45.5.6]
      7   147 ms    50 ms    49 ms  99.77.254.140
      8    49 ms    49 ms    50 ms  212.58.238.129
      9    50 ms    49 ms    49 ms  212.58.239.58
     10    51 ms    50 ms    54 ms  212.58.251.44
     11    50 ms    49 ms    49 ms  bbc-vip111.telhc.bbc.co.uk [212.58.244.66]

    Trace complete.
```

*(I have disguised the details of my on ISP's names and addresses)*

If your PC produces error messages, it is time for the last step.

### Phone your ISP's help-desk

You already pay them to provide help with this sort of problem.

### Update your question with more information

You can cut & paste your own results from nslookup, ping and tracert. In the command prompt window, click anywhere with the mouse right-button and choose "mark" from the context-menu.
Now use the mouse's left-button to select the command and response text. Press enter to copy the marked region to the clipboard. Paste into your question between lines containing <pre> and </pre>.

Answer (score 1):

A great little site at times like this is:

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Enter the address of a website and it will tell you if the site is down or if it's a problem with your connection.

Click [here](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/bbc.co.uk) for the bbc.co.uk results.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, check out my [TryAgain extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2462/)!

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching to [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/intl/hu/speed/public-dns/) or [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/).

Comment: Hm... It seems (based on Tom's answer) that you can resolve the hostname just fine, so this won't help you. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be inadvertently blocking access to the site through an application similar to [PeerBlock](http://www.peerblock.com/). For PeerBlock, you could consider allowing HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you guys can resolve that hostname just fine (based on Tom C's answer).
Your ISP could be using a transparent proxy and the error page you are seeing could originate from that. Are you seeing a browser-specific error page, or is it the same for all browsers?
If it is the same, then your ISP is using a transparent proxy, and it is having troubles.

Check for its presence:

http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test

http://www.lagado.com/tools/cache-test