# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.google.com

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, connection

My home page in Firefox [v4.0] and Internet Explorer [v9.0.8112.16421, Update Versions RTM (KB982861)] is currently set to Google but when I depress the quick start icon to start up either browser, I am getting the following immediate results:

#### Unable to connect (In Firefox)

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.google.com.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

#### Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

> What you can try:
>
> Diagnose Connection Problems
>
> More information
>
> This problem can be caused by a variety of issues, including:
>
> - Internet connectivity has been lost.
> - The website is temporarily unavailable.
> - The Domain Name Server (DNS) is not reachable.
> - The Domain Name Server (DNS) does not have a listing for the website's domain.
> - There might be a typing error in the address.
> - If this is an HTTPS (secure) address, click Tools, click Internet Options, click Advanced, and check to be sure the SSL and TLS protocols are enabled under the security section.
>
> For offline users
>
> You can still view subscribed feeds and some recently viewed webpages.
>
> To view subscribed feeds:
>
> 1. Click the Favorites button , click Feeds, and then click the feed you want to view.
>
> To view recently visited webpages (might not work on all pages):
>
> 1. Press Alt, click File, and then click Work Offline.
> 2. Click the Favorites button, click History, and then click the page you want to view.

Thankfully, I am able to use one browser that I have installed on my computer (Mathon v3.0.20.5000) to search online for technical assistance in this matter.  I have seen several WinSock error issues mentioned; but, they are pointing to Windows XP and I am using Windows 7 Pro and remain uncertain whether anything identified as a fix for one OS will work in another.

Things I've tried:

1. HiJackThis
2. Complete scan with Avira AntiVirus Premium.

What am I overlooking?  What should I do to address this problem?

Comment: Is dns working? Try ping www.google.com to see if you get an answer.
This question actually belongs to superuser.com btw.

Comment: Check proxy settings on all three browsers and use whatever settings mathon has.

Comment: Check out the [Community FAQ](http://superuser.com/tags/community-faq/info) post on **[How to diagnose not being able to access a specific website](http://superuser.com/q/231977/20088)**. It has some useful troubleshooting steps that you should try.

Answer (score 1):

Go to START -> and in search field type CMD and press enter. After black window shows up type in `ping google.com` and see if it responds. If it doesn't then DNS probably is not working or is not set correctly. This is basic test and it would be nice if you can provide this.