# 2 workstations won't connect to most websites, but will connect to some

Tags: internet-connection

I have a very frustrating issue I wasn't able to solve:
2 workstations which are used by the same user are not able to connect to most websites receivin a timeout, however they will load some websites specificly from my country. They are able to get the website addresses via DNS.
Both stations have their internet connection through a remote router.
Other stations in the same LAN are connecting fine.

Here's what I tried:

- Virus scan
- Renewing IPs
- Reseting the workstations
- Moving one workstation to a different RJ-45 in the wall
- Reseting the hub and switch
- Checking the hosts file
- DNS flush

Nothing seems to help. I am preparing a CD with more AV tools to see if there's anything hiding on the stations.

UPDATE:
It was an incorrect configuration in "Internet Options". I configured the correct proxy and now it works.

Comment: Which OS? Which websites? Tried different browsrs? Do they ping? Does traceroute return a positive path? Have a look at this question - [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user](http://superuser.com/q/231977/4377)

Comment: OS is XP, websites: basicly any except few which have a dns ending from my country. No ping, but there is also no ping from station that do load the websites, this can be set in the network they connect through. Traceroute is also gone after the 5th hoop, but that happens on all workstations including the ones that do connect.

Comment: do you have a proxy / firewall / webfilter? Is it set to stop all traffic towards those site, originating from the workstations?

Comment: tried switching DNS to 8.8.8.8 or 4.2.2.2 (if that's allowed) to see if its a DNS issue?

Comment: SOLVED: It was an issue with the proxy configuration.The client connects through a proxy, and it was configured incorrectly.