# Tumblr custom domains don't load at all

Tags: macos, mac, dns, domain, tumblr

This seems really obscure, but for some reason ALL Tumblr sites that use a custom domain don't load for me. Regular Tumblr subdomains do load, though.

For instance, this loads for me: http://authenticjobs.tumblr.com

This does not: http://blog.fetchnotes.com (it's a Tumblr site on a custom domain)

It's that case for *any* Tumblr site with a custom domain and it's been like this for at least a couple of weeks.

What on earth could be making that happen? I don't notice it on any other sites.

I'm running Mac OS X (10.7.3).

Things I've tried:

- Restarting computer
- Power cycling modem
- Power cycling router
- Trying different browsers
- Checked http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com
- Pinged (and I'm able to ping without issue)
- Changed devices (tried my iPhone...it worked on 3G but did NOT work when on the same Wi-Fi network)

Comment: Restarting my computer and power cycling modem and router. Really have no idea what else to try.

Comment: Using a different browser, pinging the hostnames to see whether they can be resolved, different computer on the same network, same computer on a different network. Doing what [this topics](http://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user) suggests.

Comment: Just updated my post with what I've tried.

Comment: Does blog.fetchnotes.com resolve to 72.32.231.8 for you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you write "Does not load"?

Comment: Yes, it does resolve that IP. And "does not load" meaning browsers throw their message saying the server can't be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem for a few months, but I think I've fixed it. I was using google's IPv4 DNS addresses (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and I just switched them to the IPv6 options
(2001:4860:4860::8888 / 2001:4860:4860::8844) and it's tentatively fixed.