# Can not access www.websaru.com

Tags: security, ip, hosts

I am unable to access the website www.websaru.com. I'm in China, is the website blocked? I don't think so,  because it is not a sensitive website. How can I access it? Please help.

Comment: Works for me.  http://www.isup.me/www.websaru.com also says it works. Might be the firewall

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user

Answer (score 1):

According to [BlockedInChina.net](http://www.blockedinchina.net/?siteurl=http://www.websaru.com/) (checked 10:22 PM CDT on 23 June 2012), accessing the site www.websaru.com is getting timeouts.  This might mean that the website is blocked, at least partially.

**UPDATE (10:33 PM CDT on 23 June 2012):** *After doing a bit of research, the following method does not seem to be illegal in China.*

### Accessing Blocked Websites in China

*I personally confirmed that this method worked on 18 June 2012.*

1. Download the [Obfsproxy Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy.html.en) for your operating system.
2. Extract the package.
3. Run the executable file inside the first directory level.
4. Mozilla Firefox should open, and a page should load stating that Tor is configured for it.
5. You can now access any website (even even [websaru.com](http://www.websaru.com/)) that an uncensored connection can access.