# Website not accessible on my system though others are able to access it on same network

Tags: internet, browser, website, http-status-code-404

Whenever I try accessing dailymotion.com, I get following error:

"**Not Found**

*The requested URL was not found on this server*."

I was able to access this website till last week but now its always giving a Not Found error.

I tried searching for solution and after going through various links (esp. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user)) I tried following but to no avail:

*a. Tried accessing website using different browsers but all give same result of Not Found*

*b. Tried accessing website on different networks but again its the same error of Not Found, though other computers on same network are able to access it*

*c. Used ipconfig /flushdns but still the error persists*

*d. Checked the host file for entry at drivers\etc but didn't find any entry for dailymotion.com*

*e. Accessed the website using its IP address but still the same error of Not Found*

When I ping website from command prompt then I am able to receive the reply but browser always displays Not Found.

There is Sophos installed on my system but its Web Control is not accessible to me. There are many websites, like proxies etc.. which are blocked by Sophos, but all of them display the message of "Website Blocked" when tried to access. But dailymotion displays error message as Not Found.

Thus, **could someone please guide that what can be the reason behind this and how it can be resolved? Also, can Sophos display a Not Found error?**

My system runs Windows 7. Please let me know if I need to furnish any other information on this.

Thanks in advance.

**Important Update**: Evaluating things further I found that when I try accessing this website using a broadband dongle then it opens up all fine, but when I try using LAN then it doesn't open no matter which network I am in. What can be the reason behind this and how can this be fixed? Any help anyone? Thanks.

Comment: I would assume it is the anti-virus even though there is no page saying website is blocked. Try to find a online proxy and go to dailymotion.com

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks, I tried using an online proxy, like hide.me/proxy, and was able to open dailymotion.com. Does this confirm that its antivirus which is blocking it?

Also, can this be addressed anyway from my system so that its not blocked, given that fact that I don't have Web Control access though.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem when my router kept blocking a site related to my work. I could access the site directly, but not with the router as a switch or through Wifi. The internet service provided said it was router problem and that I should ditch it and buy new one.

I tried steps such as DNS flushing, malware detection, system restore, cache clear, changing the ip address, MAC, etc. Nothing solved my problem. I tried accessing the site through proxy and I could , but couldn't download the files related to my work. That is when I tried Tor browser and finally after battling this problem for 2 days, i was able to access my website through Tor and even download the files, which the proxy sites wouldn't let me do.

I hope this helps someone.