# can't ping, can't browse, just one site, not dns

Tags: networking, connection, ping, traceroute

Ok this is a new one for me cuz i can NOT browse and also NOT ping and it's just one site but the site is up and it happens from 3 different computers (all windows 7) behind my router-cable_modem.

First noticed i could not browse to websudoku.com.
But isup.me/websudoku.com said "it's just you". (isup.me aka downforeveryoneorjustme.com)

And downoruprightnow.com/status/websudoku.com said it's up (I like their "Troubleshooting Tips"--all of which i tried).

isitup.org/websudoku.com also said it was up:

```
It took 39 ms for a 200 response code with an ip of 66.39.22.227.
```

> THIS DNS TURNED OUT TO BE *A* PROBLEM, BUT NOT THE REAL PROBLEM.
>
> So i tried to dns. could not. tried nslookup websudoku.com 8.8.8.8 (ie
>   google dns) and it worked. so i set my dns to opendns and google
>   followed by comcast (my isp--in NJ, USA (between New York and
>   Philadelphia, PA, for international readers)).
>
> But, nslookup with no dns server specified still could not translate.
>   It was using an IPv6 DNS by default, so i changed that to, again,
>   OpenDNS and Google IPv6 DNS.
>
> Now, i could DNS translate fine using nslookup.
>
> END DNS TACK.

However, i could still not ping 66.39.22.227 nor browse to it as a name nor number.

So i tried just-ping.com (which resolved to https://cloudmonitor.ca.com/en/ping.php; and which i learned from this deservedly popular post: [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user?](https://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user)).

Now... dont know how to interpret that result. Almost all sites had 20-40% packet loss, but they almost all returned mostly <100ms ping times.

The only other thing i tried was tracert, but after

```
6    13 ms    11 ms    13 ms  ae12.edge1.NewYork2.level3.net [4.68.127.1] 
7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

it timed out all the way to 30 hops.  Which often happens. There's nothing i can do if intermediate nodes turn of ICMP packet responses, or worse dont forward them (does that happen)?

I dont know of any other way to analyze the route between me and websudoku.com

(ironically, isup.me/isitdownrightnow.com (if you can parse that) says right now it's NOT just you--cuz at first i thot it was 2 sites only that i couldnt reach.  geesh!)

So is it the site (despite isup.me's and others' optimism)?

Is the site blocking me?

Is someone else blocking the site? virustotal.com says it's ok.

Has Net Neutrality hit? Is it the FCC? ;)

firewall?

Is it an intermediate internet route problem?

More importantly, how can i tell?!? I like being able to figure out things like this.

---

Thanks @SchylerJones for your answer. Seem my comment in reply to it. Here's my tracert this morning:

```
C:\Users\NAME>tracert websudoku.com

Tracing route to websudoku.com [66.39.22.227] over a maximum of 30 hops:

 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
 2     9 ms     8 ms     9 ms  [witheld]
 3     8 ms     8 ms    14 ms  xe-4-0-0-32767sur01.hillsboro.nj.panjde.comcast.net [68.85.128.133]
 4    11 ms    10 ms    25 ms  ae-18-0ar03.plainfield.nj.panjde.comcast.net [68.85.62.65]
 5    13 ms    12 ms    15 ms  he-5-12-0-0-r01.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.90.21]
 6    11 ms    11 ms    11 ms  ae12.edge1.NewYork2.level3.net [4.68.127.1] <<<----
 7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 8    22 ms    21 ms    21 ms  ae-2-19.bear1.Pittsburgh3.Level3.net [4.69.203.241]
 9    90 ms   203 ms   203 ms  ae-5-5.car1.Pittsburgh3.Level3.net [4.69.135.241]
10    22 ms    23 ms    22 ms  4.34.30.22
11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
12    22 ms    21 ms    21 ms  websudoku.com [66.39.22.227]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: so...that's a little frustrating. @Schyler gave the answer and i tried to put this tracert in a comment to his answer. But, it was too long for the comment. RESTRICTION. So posted it as an "answer" instead but people here are objecting to that. RESTRICTION. When someone is trying to participate and keeps tripping over restrictions...it's frustrating. Also, it IS an answer. But perhaps not explained well (because the text is in my comment to Schyler). It is a ping on the next day showing that now ae12.edge1.NewYork2.level3.net NOW DOES pass pings thru it. That confirms Schler's answer. sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ae12.edge1.NewYork2.level3.net does not appear to be passing traffic. The effects of the problem are sporadic and widespread. https://downdetector.com/status/level3?fb_action_ids=10205484876232871&fb_action_types=og.comments

Comment: So this was the 1 time in 100 that ping Request time outs were a real data point? Ok i will remember this. Also that means the just-ping.com packet losses were a real clue also. Did you look up that level3.net address in downdetector? I have only used that for final destinations.  See my new tracert in an "answer" cuz it's too long for a comment, but yes that appears to have been the problem,

Comment: I can't up-vote you because I don't have enough reputation, but know in your heart that I would've ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar cases when I worked at an isp company. Most of which the following commands ended up working for some but others related a different issue. You could try it and see if it makes a difference.Run cmd in administration mode and type

> netsh i ip log.txt

Followed by

> netsh winsock reset.

If all goes well restart your pc and try doing a browse test followed by ping test for results. Also almost very unlikely but changing the MTU within the modem settings to something a bit lower. Something like 1425 or 1400. But no less and try again. In the past for specific website and or general browsing issues related to network, these commands and configuration changes helped fixed the issues.  So give it ago.

Comment: the `netsh i ip log.txt` does not work on my Windows 7 system. Did you mean `netsh i ip dump > log.txt`? Maybe it was a formatting thing with the angle brackets? The `netsh winsock reset` i'll keep in mind. How does that compare to disabling and re-enabling the network adapter (which i did try)?