# Can't reach the websites of social media like facebook, instagram, and linkedin

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, connection, social-networking

Here is the screenshot of my browser when I tried to reach these websites. For some reason, something is blocking the connection.

[image: Screenshot]

Other than that:

1. Internet connection is stable, my download speed on steam is 10mb/s
2. I am using my school's wifi, I am not sure if others can use those networks, but I can use instagram on my phone using school's wifi.
3. I am not using vpn
4. I do not have antivirus software running. There may be some service in the deep background running but I don't know.

5.DNS Client is running

6.This problem existed for months. So I tried reboot, and reconnected several times.

7. Is there anyway I can check the blacklist of my IP address? Maybe I somehow set a list of websites to block. I remembered I have downloaded a hosts file online to block a lot of websites. But it makes my laptop super slow and laggy, so I deleted it long ago. I will display my current hosts file down below, mainly blocking some porn websites tho.

My current connected wifi properties are like this:
[image: Connected wifi properties]

My etc folder:

[image]

My hosts file:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, is this your personal PC/laptop or is it schools property?. Some Schools have Wi-Fi rules to block some sites, if so we can't help you. You need to talk to your school administrator, so they can give you access to these sites.

Comment: @human_rosas Yeah it is my personal laptop. I think you are right, they block some websites, since I can't reach those websites through phones either. I will try again when I came back home using my own wifi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user?](https://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user)

Comment: @ShaneLi In your question you are stating that you CAN reach the website via your phone: `but I can use instagram on my phone using school's wifi`. Which one is it?